# Prevent unauthorized person from uninstalling my android app

Tags: android, uninstallation

I am working on anti theft Application.I want only authorized users to uninstall my app.Like, when they try to uninstall my app they must enter a valid password and proceed.I dont wanna block uninstallation of other apps that user have installed..is there a specific way to do that..?

Answer (score 7):

If you're on an un-rooted device without a custom version of Android the only way that could be possible is making your app a [device-admin](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html) app:

> To uninstall an existing device admin application, users need to first unregister the application as an administrator.

Comment: Sorry for delay..Menwhile i was working on another project..thats k even if i make my app as device admin app anyone who steal that device can goto settings and disable device admin permission for my app..right..?

Answer (score -1):

You wanna protect apps from unauthorised access right? First, you need to download APPLOCK from play store. Setup the applock app after you download it by registering it with your email and create a pin password, then on the app you can lock the apps you want to lock.     The applock app will b useless as at this point because any smart person can simply just uninstall the applock app and then all the locks you put on your apps will disappear with the applick app thereby rendering complete unauthorised access to all your apps.
What you to do then is to go to your phone's administrative setting and make the applock app an administrator.